# animation-x invalid property value

Tags: css

I am trying to create an animation but when I use the following css:

```
.drop.animation {
  animation-name: ripple;
  animation-duration: 0.65s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

I get an error in the chrome developer tools that states beside an orange triangle with an exclamation mark that all of those are "invalid property values".

What are the proper values? I am trying to use [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you are in **Chrome**, you would use the `-webkit-` prefix for those values:

```
.drop.animation {
    -webkit-animation-name: ripple;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.65s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Also there was a typo in the last property.

Comment: Don't leave out the unprefixed properties. Other browsers like IE and Firefox use them.

Comment: Yes, you should use the `-moz-` and `-o-` prefixes too, and keep the original properties. It makes the css 4x longer, but is needed. I love to use a script called prefixfree taht does all of this by its own so I only have to use properties without prefixes.